# time conversion using time.In() is not accurate

Tags: go, time, location, datetime-conversion

When I tried to convert time `12:30 UTC` into desired timezone ie. `Asia/Calcutta (+5:30)`, which is expected to return `18:00 IST` using `t.In()` function, actually returning `18:23`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

const timeLayout string = "15:04"

func main() {
    location, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Calcutta")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unable to understand the timezone: %v", err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    t, err := time.Parse(timeLayout, "12:30") // 12:30 is in UTC
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unable to parse the time timezone: %v", err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    timeAsPerTimeZone := t.In(location) // expected: 12:30 + 5:30 = 18:00 IST
    fmt.Println(timeAsPerTimeZone.String())

    timing := "Minutes: " + strconv.Itoa(timeAsPerTimeZone.Minute()) + " Hours: " + strconv.Itoa(timeAsPerTimeZone.Hour())
    fmt.Println(timing)

}
```

Playground Link: https://go.dev/play/p/OdlFYTPfcNM

Comment: You’re parsing the time for the year 0000. Apparently that time zone was once +0553

Comment: see [Time in India - Former timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India#Former_timezones) and [Calcutta time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcutta_Time) on wikipedia. There once was a Calcutta time which was UTC+5:53:20 (yes: as in 20 seconds) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: for some reason, the description of the old timezone loaded by go on the playground shifts by 28 seconds https://go.dev/play/p/8iHT1H9GZiz -- I'm not running down that rabbit hole to see why :D

Comment: See the [time.Location](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Location) documentation.  A location maps an **instant in time** to the zone in use at that instant in time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a related github issue [time.Format invalid data](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10297)

Comment from member: [#issuecomment-88140297](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10297#issuecomment-88140297)

> Timezone depends on the date, according to 2015b version of tzdata:

To make it work as expected we also need to consider the date while parsing the time.

[Go Playground: Solution](https://go.dev/play/p/p7hmQM63RjB)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

// considered year in the format
const timeLayout string = "2006 15:04"

func main() {
    location, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Calcutta")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unable to understand the timezone: %v", err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    t, err := time.Parse(timeLayout, "2023 12:30") // 12:30 is in UTC
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unable to parse the time timezone: %v", err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    timeAsPerTimeZone := t.In(location) // expected: 12:30 + 5:30 = 18:00 IST
    fmt.Println(timeAsPerTimeZone.String())

    timing := "Minutes: " + strconv.Itoa(timeAsPerTimeZone.Minute()) + " Hours: " + strconv.Itoa(timeAsPerTimeZone.Hour())
    fmt.Println(timing)

}
```

Another detailed blog around this issue: https://www.sobyte.net/post/2022-01/golang-time/

Comment: The definitive documentation on the topic is found in the [time package documentation](https://godoc.org/time#Location) : *A Location maps time instants to the zone in use at that time. Typically, the Location represents the collection of time offsets in use in a geographical area. For many Locations the time offset varies depending on whether daylight savings time is in use at the time instant.* Note that the mapping is for **time instants**, not time of day. Also note that a location can have multiple time offsets.